# How can I install CF 2.0 on my handheld device, and which version/architecture?

Tags: compact-framework, windows-ce, motorola, .net-cf-3.5, wce

To install CF 2.0 on my handheld device (replacing the existing/unwanted version 3.5), according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172491%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (straight from the horse's mouth), I need to run netcfsetupv2.msi from the following directory:

```
\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0\CompactFramework
```

I have one problem with that, though: I have no netcfsetupv2.msi - not there or anywhere else, in fact (although I do have a *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0 folder*).

I do see "interesting" files such as netcflaunch.exe in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE\wce400\x86
```

...and that same filename also in the armv4 folder (as opposed to x86) and others, also several versions beneath \wce500 as well.

So, assuming I should run netcflaunch.exe from my PC (with an ActiveStync connection) to install CF 2.0 on my handheld device, which version of  netcflaunch.exe should I run for a Motorola 3190 running OS Version 6.00.000 Windows CE Version 6.00?

My guess is *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v2.0\WindowsCE
\wce500\x86\netcflaunch.exe*, but that's all it is - a guess.

Comment: If you have Compact Framework runtimes already on your PC you can follow http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788171%28v=vs.90%29.aspx to find the right CAB file to install CF2. But NORMALLY there is no need to install NetCF2 onto a device with NetCF3.5. And the install of NetCF2 will NOT replace NetCF3.5 on the device, it will be installed side-by-side.

Comment: According to a txt file I found on the device: Device CPU: 'ARMV4I'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply install the CF 2.0 cab file on the device.  Side-by-side installation is supported. 
That said, why would you do that?  If it has CF 3.5, it can already run CF 2.0 applications.  "Downgrading" is a useless waste of disk space.

Comment: Because according to the erstwhile project lead/dev (who has absquatulated), we cannot install v. 3.5 due to space constraints on the device. I want to uninstall v. 3.5 and then install 2.0

Comment: That makes no sense.  You can't install 3.5 due to space constraints, but you want to uninstall it?  If you want to uninstall it, then it must be there, therefore installing it is not required.

Comment: "That makes no sense." True; I think he meant having it there does not leave enough space for other things to run (space is extremely tight/limited). We have to fiddle with the memory slider when things go pear-shaped.

Comment: If it's in ROM, there's no way to remove it.

Comment: I realized what is probably the main reason for the "3.5 == bad juju" mantra stemming from a nearby cubicle (since abandoned): there are hundreds of devices in the field that would have to be upgraded to the new version which, in practice, would probably require them being sent back to us, updated, and then sent back - not a pretty thought, seeing they would be without the devices for several days, plus the cost of shipping and tweaking time.